# interesting ContentControl binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contentcontrol

First off I should say I an a newbie programmer and all help is appreciated. I'm currently working on a wpf application in which I would like to have usercontrol that has a label and a contentcontrol which can be updated based on which button is selected from the welcome view. like so

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControl.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentControl.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ContentControl.Views"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">  
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ScreenViewModel}">
        <views:ScreenView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WelcomeViewModel}">
        <views:WelcomeView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MeetingRoomViewModel}">
        <views:MeetingRoomView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
        <views:DashboardView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>This Is My Label</Label>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainPanel" Content="{Binding Path=Content}"
            MinHeight="200"
            MinWidth="200"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Focusable="False">
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MainPanel.Content = new WelcomeView();
        MainPanel.Content = this.MainPanel.Content;
    }
}
```

Here is the WelcomeViewModel:

```
internal class WelcomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowVm;
    private RelayCommand<string> _viewChangedCommand;

    public ICommand ViewChangedCommand
    {
        get { return _viewChangedCommand ?? (_viewChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnViewChanged)); }
    }

    public event EventHandler ViewChanged;

    private void OnViewChanged(string view)
    {
        EventHandler handler = ViewChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(view, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowVm
    {
        get { return _mainWindowVm; }
        set
        {
            _mainWindowVm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainViewModel");
        }
    }

    public WelcomeViewModel()
    {
        MainWindowVm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        ViewChanged += MainWindowVm.ViewChanged;
    }
}
```

And lastly my welcome.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControl.Views.WelcomeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentControl.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:WelcomeViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White">
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="DASH" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="Dashboard"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="ROOM" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="MeetingRoom"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="SCREEN" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="Screen" />
    </DockPanel>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Blue"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So the issue is when the ViewChange Event is fired off it is seen in the MainWindowViewModel however when it uses the PropertyEventHandler(as seen below) the PropertyChanged is always null.

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you have some WPF, Bindings, and Mvvm mistakes...
First, why do you do this:

```
MainPanel.Content = this.MainPanel.Content;
```

that is the same as:

```
MainPanel.Content = MainPanel.Content;
```

this line is unecesary.

Second why you said:

```
Content="{Binding Path=Content}"
```

but then you set in your code behind:

```
MainPanel.Content = new WelcomeView();
```

Here you may have a conceptual error: When you set a binding by default this binding will be done to the DataContext of the control itself (the UserControl in this case).
Ok, to solve this and work with Mvvm, lets to keep the binding:

```
Content="{Binding Path=Content}"
```

But now we need to set the UserControl datacontext:

```
MainPanel.DataContext = new MainPanelViewModel();
```

And now we need to create a property in the MainPanelViewModel called Content.
Inside this property you will set the content that you want to show in the ContentControl.Content. (In this case a WelcomeViewModel and anything you want)

Hope this answer help to you to start with wpf and mvvm. it is a great platform.

Comment: Main Panel is the Name of the Content Control. I want the MainPanel to be a container for different views. Hence setting it to WelcomeView(); then I want to be able to bind to different views to the MainPanel by button selection which in in the first view bound (welcomeView).

Comment: Then this different views you should to set them in the Content property of your view model. But then the Command that change the views (ViewChangedCommand) also should be inside the ViewModel (example MainPanelViewModel)

Comment: You should to create a new class (in this case a call it MainPanelViewModel), that will be the ViewModel for the MainPanel contentControl, then you should set this class as the DataContext of the MainPanel ContentControl or MainWindow. Then in this class set the Content property and the ViewChangedCommand. The view changed command set the content property (the content that you would show on your MainPanel)

Comment: I want to use one class for this why do I need two? Can you point to an example (code)

Comment: Do you need a view Model for each logical view, in this case the MainPanelViewModel that i said could be the view model for the main windo (also you should name it MainWindowViewModel). And the WelcomeViewModel should work as the view model for the Welcom View. The idea is that you set a WelcomeViewModel in the Content of the MainPanelViewModel, and the WelcomeView load. (load on the content of the COntentControl)

Comment: Have you heared about MvvMLigth, it is excellent for MvvmApplications

Comment: Yes so my project consists of a MainWindowView, MainWindowViewModel (which is the view that I would like to show other views in) the other files are WelcomeView, WelcomeViewModel and ScreenView,ScreenViewModel. The whole Idea is to have the MainWindow view shown with the Welcome View inside a contentcontrol (on the MainWindowView) then when you press a Button on the WelcomeView it Changes the MainWindowView's contentcontrol to show the ScreenView within it.

Comment: A good example is your other question (Wpf contentControl) you have a MainWindowViewModel, in this ViewModel you should put the Commands and the Content property, and then in the commands change the content.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to DO!

Comment: Thanks guys I figured this out

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Mistakes you could fix:

- dont change MainPanel.Content in code-behind. It's supposed to be changed in ViewModel through binding.
- In your Window.Resources, note that you're setting DataContext to MainViewModel of WelcomeView, and in WelcomeView you want it to be WelcomeIewModel. It does not work like that. The DataCOntext=WelcomeViewModel is overriden by the Window.Resources
- why are you creating new MainViewmodel in WelcomeViewModel?
- PropertyChanged is null because you are not using it in the View(that specific MainiewMOdel instance). If you're gonna bind against it, the PropertyChanged will reciee new event-listener and wont be null anymore.

Perhaps explain your problem a little better and I can give further information.

Comment: I changed it in code behind to initialize it with welcomeView. I created the MainViewModel in Welcome so I can listen for the ViewChanged event. ' MainWindowVm = new MainWindowViewModel();
            ViewChanged += MainWindowVm.ViewChanged;'  how do i get that specific instance?